# Xamp mysql already running

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image]

When xamp starts mysql shows already running..[image: Http://localhost/phpmyadmin shows like this]

I cant access mysql. what will do
when access php myadmin it shows #2002 - Connection refused
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: Can you connect from other MySQL clients, such as the command line one?

Comment: BTW, it's always better to post error messages as text. That makes them searchable and easier to read.

Comment: I did not install another mysqll. Only install via xamp.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Xampp bundle does not include the command-line client? What happens when you type `mysql` in a shell?

Comment: When type mysql command line clent it shows                                  "The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>"

Comment: Then it's true, Xampp doesn't include the command-line client. Sorry, I can't really help you. I tend to avoid third-party bundles because I'm not smart enough to use them O<:-)